# What's the name of this background design pattern?

Tags: patterns, texture

What's the name of the texture / design pattern found in the background of this site? http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/

What should I search on Google to find out similar textures?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called a Voronoi (cell/noise) pattern. See:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)
- Photoshop has a Voronoi pattern filter: its called [crystallize](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/filter-effects-reference.html#pixelate_filters)

[image: crystal]

**Image 1**: A Voronoi pattern, usinhg Photoshop crystallize. Its often a good idea to trim the corner cells away. And if possible do the cells yourself.

*Fun link*: A interactive [Voronoi pattern](http://paperjs.org/examples/voronoi/) click to add new cells.

**Edity**: this can also be the dual solution of voronoi that is called a Delunlay triangulation.